# Displaying a Downward Triangle in VB.NET ▼ (U+25BC)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, unicode, character-encoding, escaping

Hey,  I'm trying to figure out how to display the ▼ character properly in a .NET winform application.

I am creating a custom control, and for the button, I want this character to appear.  I am able to set the text to this character, but it appears as a blank square.

Any ideas on what I need to do to make this character appear properly on my forms?

I am using Arial font, which is compatible with this symbol.

**EDIT**: It is currently being set as follows:

```
btnCalendarToggle.Text = "▼"  'Yes, it appears exactly like this in my code
```

More information on the character can be found here:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/index.htm

**EDIT2**: I tried adding some other Unicode characters, and got the following message:

> "Some Unicode Characters in this file
>   cannot be saved in the current
>   codepage.  Do you want to resave this
>   file as Unicode in order to Maintain
>   your data?"

After clicking YES on this message, it still didn't work.  It appears that the encoding method may be wrong for the file... I don't know what to set it to.  Has anyone else tried to display this character in a winform before?

Comment: If all you are using this for is a button and it is only to display the visual concept of a down arrow then I would simply use an image for the button.

Comment: Suggest you either use an image or use the explicit escape sequence as ShuggyCoUk suggested. Changing your souce code files as unicode may cause issues with source control

Comment: It is working fine now, using UTF-8 encoding.  The escape sequence is the way to go.  Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There can often be issues (both with source control systes and diff tools) if you embed more complex unicode characters in source files.

It is often better to do it via an explicit escape sequence and keep the source file in a simpler encoding.

```
btnCalendarToggle.Text = "\u25BC";
```

If this works it is likely that the problem is instead the encoding settings for the source file.

Are you certain however that the font in question is Arial (try debugging and checking) since regardless of the above mentioned issues so long as the encoding is set to a legitimate Unicode one (and Visual Studio will convert the file for you if you embed such a character in it) this should have worked.

Comment: Just for reference, the up arrow is btnCalendarToggle.Text = "\u25B2";

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code you are currently using ?

You can print out characters using the chr(int) function if you know the character code.

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To 255
    txtTest.Text = txtTest.Text & Chr(i) & " -- " & i.ToString() & Environment.NewLine
Next i
```

Try that and see if your character prints out.